# Exclamation mark by settings icon (the Chrome Menu) in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I recently installed an extension to Google Chrome called [Page Monitor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pemhgklkefakciniebenbfclihhmmfcd), and since then gGoogle shows a small exclamation mark by the Chrome menu icon for the browser settings (see screenshot below).

What does this mean?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that an extension has been updated with new permissions.

Since an update was pushed to the extension which requires more permissions than originally granted, Chrome indicates this by means of the exclamation mark.

Previously, Chrome would show a message about Extension X was disabled due to change in permissions.

However, the behaviour that you see now is due to change in the way Chrome handles the situation - [Chrome will no longer display the message](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=121436#c2). Instead, it'll show the exclamation mark in the Chrome Menu icon just as how you see it.

Comment: But I have no disabled extensions installed...

Comment: @TomasLycken disabled or not, shouldn't matter - updated the answer

Answer (score 6):

Chrome could be out of sync. Go to `Settings -> Sign In` to correct this.

Comment: Yes. This happened to me after I signed out of my gmail account.

Comment: +1 worked for me. I have changed my gmail password and forgot to update on chrome.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this link](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=121436), Chrome does this when a new extension is requesting new permissions. So, if you set the permissions, it should go away.

Answer (score 1):

It might be because you enabled 2-step authentication for you Google Account and Chrome cannot login anymore. You have to create a [application specific password](http://google.com/account) and use it to sign in to Chrome.